# Rack throwing EOFError (bad content body)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

We're using Ruby 2.1.2, Rails 3.2.19 with JQuery 1.11, asset pipeline is not being used (so not using JQuery-ujs, but are using relevant rails.js explicitly). For most users, JQuery and other related common plugins are being pulled from Google CDN (including jquery.form 3.50).  The web server affected is Ubuntu 14.04, Nginx 1.6, and Passenger 4.x.

For about 10% of users on our production server (loads seem to not matter), we're getting a stack dump like this, primarily for one URL but there are others:

```
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:74 in "block in fast_forward_to_first_boundary"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:72 in "loop"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:72 in "fast_forward_to_first_boundary"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:15 in "parse"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/multipart.rb:25 in "parse_multipart"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/request.rb:336 in "parse_multipart"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/request.rb:201 in "POST"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:237 in "POST"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:10 in "parameters"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_parameters.rb:31 in "filtered_parameters"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:31 in "process_action"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121 in "process"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45 in "process"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203 in "dispatch"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14 in "dispatch"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246 in "block in action"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73 in "call"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73 in "dispatch"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36 in "call"
/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68 in "block in call"
/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56 in "each"
/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56 in "call"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:50 in "traced_call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:26 in "traced_call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23 in "traced_call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55 in "call"
/gems/oink-0.10.1/lib/oink/middleware.rb:17 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35 in "block in call"
/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34 in "catch"
/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210 in "context"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28 in "block in call"
/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405 in "_run__3807242266783802268__call__1942732928323145202__callbacks"
/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405 in "__run_callback"
/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385 in "_run_call_callbacks"
/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81 in "run_callbacks"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:102 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32 in "call_app"
/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:18 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136 in "forward"
/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245 in "fetch"
/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185 in "lookup"
/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66 in "call!"
/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:484 in "call"
/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application.rb:231 in "call"
/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30 in "method_missing"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64 in "block in call"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49 in "each"
/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54 in "call"
/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.3.241/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57 in "call"
/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74 in "process_request"
/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141 in "accept_and_process_next_request"
/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109 in "main_loop"
/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448 in "block (3 levels) in start_threads"
```

Before an upgrade to JQuery 1.11 from 1.5(!), this error didn't occur (or if it did, it was very rare).  We so far have been unable to reproduce this error either on our staging server or in a development environment.  A support person saw it on production once (I've tried several times), but couldn't replicate on staging (which is same environment as production, though smaller resourcing). JQuery migrate is not showing any issues when it runs and, as I said, it seems to work for most users; during debug sessions nothing seems amiss.  There is no apparent pattern to OS/platform or browser (tried to reproduce on several and logs don't indicate a pattern though hard to sift enough to be sure).  The primary URL involved is for a #new action on a form controller. We have several other forms in the platform and they do not show any issues.

Since I can't reproduce it, giving a code snippet is not possible -- I wouldn't know what to pinpoint.

My interpretation of the error so far (based on first line in stack dump) is one of the three things:

1. the content is otherwise correct, but not fully formed somehow,
2. the content is poorly formed suggesting a Ruby bug (though
   perhaps JS)
3. bad encoding (I'm using form_for in Ruby and even
   threw in "multipart: true" to be explicit)

I see Rack has dealt with a related multipart EOFError issue in 4.x, but we're running Rails 3.2.19 which locks us at an older version and upgrading to Rails 4.x is not practical at this time.   As a test, I've tried JQuery back to as low as 1.7 but didn't seem to change the behavior (any older and I'd have to drop code updates needed for JQuery 1.8+).

Since the JQuery code necessitated changes to our JS, I suspected I missed some necessary JS changes, but nothing seems amiss.  There were also some CSS changes nearby, but I don't see how that could affect things (since everything was passing in our various test environments, other changes were also included in the deploy).

I've been suspecting JS issues primarily, but some limited tests on production (I have to be careful on the live server so can't get too aggressive) haven't shown any clues or thrown any errors that seem related.

As background, I have about a year's experience with Ruby and JS (though many more years on other programming platforms) so entirely possible it's something basic I'm unfamiliar with.

I'm having a hard time with narrowing down where to focus to get a handle on this.  Any advice either to diagnose or solve?

**UPDATE (10/11/14)**  I monkey patched `Rack::Multipart::Parser.fast_forward_to_first_boundary` (thanks, Isaac Betesh!) to add log traces and confirmed that the content passed to the parser is empty when it reaches that function (that is, the StringIO referred to by `@env['rack.input']` during multipart parsing returns no data). My theory now is that it erroneously expects multipart data when there is there is none.   Again, this only happens intermittently and parses fine for many other invocations of this same page.  Since we're running under Passenger 4.x and Nginx, I haven't ruled out a buffering issue.

Comment: If you can't upgrade Rack because Rails 3 is locking the version, try monkey-patching the individual class in the file at the top of the stack trace.  You might not figure out why this is happening but it may still be an effective workaround.

Comment: I could, but was worried about changing stock code on production (given that I really can't test it first without reproduction), might give me a clue though if it changes the behavior and if it makes life easier for users, it may be worth it. Thanks.

Comment: Also, this same code seemed fine before upgrades to Jquery and related changes to the JS (given other changes in same deploy this a probabalistic statement).  So the change in Jquery would have had to somehow trigger the failure in Rack, so is my other reason for hesitation.

Comment: Which routes and which formats is this occurring with?  If it's only happening on AJAX requests, that might explain the connection.  If so, it could be that jquery is not formatting the data properly on those AJAX requests.

Comment: Yes, the most affected URL is indeed involving AJAX.  Is there a good way to see what the specific request being sent by the AJAX submit is (this is definitely where my inexperience might be getting in the way)?  I'm not seeing enough detail on the rails-side log to get a handle on it.

Comment: 1) You can look in your server logs.  For instance, if you're running Apache on Linux, look in `/var/log/httpd/`.  You can edit your Apache configuration to log more verbosely until you've solved the issue.  That way you'll be able to see the full request.

Comment: 2) Have Rails log the full environment on each request. You'll need to create a simple piece of middleware that just logs `env.inspect` before passing `env` to the next layer of middleware.  See https://gist.github.com/betesh/275c55abe7436417177b

Comment: 3) If you can consistenly reproduce the error, or if a user reports that he got an error and his browser is still open, you can use the browser's development tools to see exactly what was sent to the server.

Comment: Thank you @IsaacBetesh, I'll try those... I think you might have put me on the right track.  I'll add an update after I've tried it.

Comment: Did your #2 (#1 for Nginx didn't yield and I didn't want to count on #3 since its not consistent). The #2 though was great, that's some verbose logging.  BTW, I didn't answer a question you had: for the primary URL involved, it's AJAX of a form submission, so should be HTML.   Hopefully, I'll be able to contrast a log entry for a failed one and a successful one and get a useful lead.  Thanks, I'll post an update after I collect some results.

Comment: #2 revealed much about the environment (which I learned a lot about in general from going through the data) but not much about the payload submitted in the form (my inconclusive inference is that it's 0 bytes in failed submissions).  However, I did see inconsistencies about the content type between successful and failed queries that I'm running down.  In any case, though it's still a needle-in-a-haystack search for me, it's allowed me to focus on some new potential causes, so that's something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was finally solved and I'm posting what happened in case it's helpful to others.

**Summary** The original code contained an ajaxSubmit (via jquery.form plugin) in the JS which submitted a form (as a POST) with multipart/form-data encoding (so far so good).  The rails controller handling the submission processed the data normally and then *redirected* to a second href (as a GET).  The browser (perhaps still processing through the jquery.form plugin before returning to it's `success` callback handler) received the redirect and *retained* the multipart/form-data encoding type.  When rack received the GET with multipart encoding still specified, it balked because there was no multipart data to parse.

Sorry, much of this wasn't in evidence in my OP.  And it's not clear to me why this worked under an older version of JQuery and the JQuery.form plugin or why it sometimes succeeded under the new JQuery/JQuery.form.

**Solution** Refactored the controller to no longer redirect, but rather return a URL (as a text render) for the `success` callback handler of the original ajaxSubmit.  The `success` handler now then does an AJAX GET on the returned URL thereby leaving the workflow intact but avoiding any multipart encoding on the GET request.

**tl;dr** :

Before the code was ever changed, we had a path involving Jquery.form that went something like this (code example is not meant to be executable, but just as an illustration):

*Ruby view* (in HAML for form being submitted):

```
= form_for @someObject, html: {:multipart => true, :class => "someformclass"} do |f|
  = f.error_messages
  = hidden_field_tag :submitted, true
  =# some more fields
  %p.submits
    = f.submit "Submit", class: "submit"
```

*Ruby controller*:

```
class OurController < ApplicationController
  layout false
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # some other actions

  def create
    # some processing

    someObject.save
    redirect_to new_feedback_path, :method => :get, :notice => "notice text", status: 303
  end

  # some other actions
end
```

*JS*:

```
$(document).on('click', '.someformclass .submit', function() {
  ...
  $(this).parents('form').ajaxSubmit({     // uses jquery.form
    ...
    beforeSubmit: function(someargs) {
      ... blah blah
    },
    success: function(responseText) {
      // ... code to display flash message
      if (typeof(window.history.pushState) == 'function') {
        window.history.pushState('html', 'sometext', $.cookie('current_url'));
        matchFiltersClass(window.location.pathname);
      } else {
        window.location.hash = '#!' + $.cookie('current_path');
        matchFiltersClass($.cookie('current_path'));
      }
      $('#main_content').html(responseText);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

---

This was refactored as follows (again, just an illustration):

*Ruby view* (in HAML for form being submitted):   *unchanged*

*Ruby controller*:

```
class OurController < ApplicationController
  layout false
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # some other actions

  def create
    # some processing

    someObject.save
    flash[:notice] = 'notice text'    # NEW LINE
    render text: new_feedback path, status: accepted  #CHANGED LINE
  end

  # some other actions
end
```

*JS*:

```
$(document).on('click', '.someformclass .submit', function() {
  ...
  $(this).parents('form').ajaxSubmit({     // uses jquery.form
    ...
    beforeSubmit: function(someargs) {
      ... blah blah
    },
    success: function(responseText) {
      // ... code to display flash message
      $.get(responseText, function(data) {       // NEW LINE
        if (typeof(window.history.pushState) == 'function') {
          window.history.pushState('html', 'sometext', $.cookie('current_url'));
          matchFiltersClass(window.location.pathname);
        } else {
          window.location.hash = '#!' + $.cookie('current_path');
          matchFiltersClass($.cookie('current_path'));
        }
        $('#main_content').html(responseText);
      });       // NEW LINE
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

---

This solution was found with some help with a local developer (thanks, Dan Axtman!) and not without a fair amount of time in monkey-patched logging in Rack (thanks, Isaac Betesh!).  At least I learned something about Rack and monkey patching in the process...