# Cordova App on Android using SSL sending multipart/form-data causes Rack app error: #<EOFError: bad content body>

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, cordova, ssl, puma

We have a Cordova application that connects to a rails server over SSL. It seems that our recent change from Unicorn to Puma has caused an issue where the Android App gets 500 Error when sending an image file to the server.

Some things of note:

- The iOS version of the app, built using the exact same code works perfectly fine
- Everything works fine if not using SSL
- All other requests are SSL and work fine, it is only when sending a
  multipart/form-data that the issue rears its ugly head.

I am struggling to think of what the problem might be, or even where to look for a solution. I am quite new to Puma, so I don't know if I am missing something important in my configuration for dealing with this. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

iOS request (Works fine)

```
POST /api/v2/attachments HTTP/1.1
Host: <omitted for security>
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
If-None-Match: "2146f2b315668b29682ec01973ae4155"
Accept-Language: en-us
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=+++++org.apache.cordova.formBoundary
Content-Length: 13794
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13B143 (4954749952)
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=<omitted for security>; _session_id=<omitted for security>

--+++++org.apache.cordova.formBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

Image
--+++++org.apache.cordova.formBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment[attachment]"; filename="cdv_photo_003.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 13466

iُ  B~,"
#BR$3br 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz
B   #3Rbr
$4%&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz




""""""''''',,,,,,,,,,


...................................................(<a$GW_ЬUպi&dA+x=R
?)uHv"ԊdcpIސW̚<<Kx~E1xEN]M%>r{Y_Yc<jʥYH_2r[P['6    d#wS+5Bfu

<more Binary data omitted for brevity>


--+++++org.apache.cordova.formBoundary--
```

Equivalent Android Request (Causes error)

```
POST /api/v2/attachments HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=+++++
Cookie: _session_id=<omitted for security>; XSRF-TOKEN=<omitted for security>
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0; SM-G900F Build/LRX21T)
Host: <omitted for security>
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip

--+++++
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

Image
--+++++
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment[attachment]"; filename="modified.jpg?1446611766814"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Exif

(1#%(:3=<9387@H\N@DWE78PmQW_bghg>Mqypdx\egc"
#BR$3br 

<more Binary data omitted for brevity>

--+++++--
```

There are some obvious differences in these requests, and while I wouldn't call myself an expert on the HTTP protocol, none of the differences look to me like something that would cause Puma to fall over.

The Rack Error Trace:

```
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041124+00:00 app[web.1]: 2015-11-04 04:36:07 +0000: Rack app error: #<EOFError: bad content body>
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041131+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:74:in `block in fast_forward_to_first_boundary'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041133+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:72:in `loop'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041134+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:72:in `fast_forward_to_first_boundary'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041152+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:15:in `parse'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041153+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/multipart.rb:25:in `parse_multipart'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041154+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/request.rb:377:in `parse_multipart'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041154+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/request.rb:203:in `POST'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041155+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:26:in `method_override'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041156+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:14:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041157+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.2.302/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041157+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041158+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.2.302/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041158+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-rewrite-1.5.0/lib/rack/rewrite.rb:24:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041159+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.2.302/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041159+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041160+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.2.302/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041160+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041161+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.2.302/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041161+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041161+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.2.302/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041162+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041162+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041163+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041163+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.13.2.302/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041163+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.14.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:78:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041164+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.14.0/lib/puma/server.rb:541:in `handle_request'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041164+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.14.0/lib/puma/server.rb:388:in `process_client'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041165+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.14.0/lib/puma/server.rb:270:in `block in run'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041165+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.14.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `call'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.041165+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.14.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `block in spawn_thread'
2015-11-04T04:36:07.523877+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/api/v2/attachments" host=<omitted for security> request_id=a5958dab-8c7c-4121-acc3-54d28be9ad4c fwd="<omitted for security>" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=484ms status=503 bytes=154
```

Comment: @env['rack.input'] = <Puma::NullIO:0x007f5c55007360> - I wonder if the missing Content-Length is causing the issue

Comment: Reading through the HTTP 1.1 Protocol, Content-Length header shouldn't actually be provided when using chunked encoding. The issue is 100% with Puma at this point, something with SSL and Chunked encoding is causing it to drop the body before passing on to rack. Current Fix: Disable chunked mode when using cordova-plugin-file-transfer for android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should monkey patch `Rack::Multipart::Parser.fast_forward_to_first_boundary` to add log traces and confirm that the content passed to the parser is empty when it reaches that function (that is, the `StringIO` referred to by `@env['rack.input']` during multipart parsing returns no data).

For more info : [rack-throwing-eoferror-bad-content-body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874529/rack-throwing-eoferror-bad-content-body)

Comment: I will get onto this as soon as I can. Hopefully before the bounty expires. If not, maybe I can re-add the bounty?

Comment: Try this and check whether this solves your problem. :)

Comment: Sorry - I ran out of time to award the bounty. I have some other things on my plate taking my time, I will get onto this again soon and when I do I will restart the bounty and award if it proves fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to satisfactorily resolve this issue, the source of the problem appears to be the way Puma is handling multipart/chunked data. As we are not using the most recent version, and it is not easy to upgrade at this time, I have 'hacked' a solution as below.

The odd thing here, is it appears it is the missing Content-Length header that causes the issue - despite the fact that the HTTP specification states that chunked requests shouldn't have this header.

I presume (although I could be wrong) that the SSL implementation requires a Content-Length, which is at odds with the requirement for chunked requests to not provide one.

The solution for now is to disable chunked data from the cordova app. We are using the cordova-file-transfer-plugin which allows us to set chunked to false.

Not ideal, but it does work.
From https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

```
 options.chunkedMode = false;
```

Comment: I spent an entire day trying to figure this one out. wish I had seen this answer which is the correct one! Android requires this option to be set to false. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

You should check what server log says about this 500 error